# Creating 2 jars with maven assembly plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

We can create `jar-with-dependecies` using maven assembly plugin. But I want to pack dependencies in a separate `jar` with suffix `libs`. Is it possible to do with `maven-assembly-plugin`.

Comment: First what do you mean by suffix `libs`? Something like `xyz-1.0-libs.jar`? If you mean that the answer is yes.

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes. I mean I wanted to pack all dependency into a separated jar.